# If $\sin^2 \theta + 2\cos \theta – 2 = 0$, then find the value of $\cos^3 \theta + \sec^3 \theta$

Tags: trigonometry

If $\sin^2 \theta + 2\cos \theta – 2 = 0$, then find the value of $\cos^3 \theta + \sec^3 \theta$.

Answer (score 4):

HINT:

We have $$1-\cos^2\theta+2\cos\theta-2=0\iff(\cos\theta-1)^2=0$$

---

Alternatively ,  $$1-\cos^2\theta+2\cos\theta-2=0\iff\cos^2\theta+1=2\cos\theta$$

Dividing by $\displaystyle\cos\theta$ (which is clearly $\ne0$)  $$\cos\theta+\sec\theta=2$$

Can you calculate $$\cos^3\theta+\sec^3\theta=\cos^3\theta+\frac1{\cos^3\theta}$$ from here?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Just use $\sin^2\theta = 1 - \cos^2\theta$, get the eqn in $(a-b)^2 = 0$ form. 
Then, simply use the fact that $\sec\theta = \frac1{\cos\theta}$

**Spoiler** :
!> $$\sin^2 \theta + 2\cos\theta - 2 = 0 \\
\implies 1 - \cos^2\theta + 2\cos\theta -2 = 0\\
\implies -(\cos^2\theta - 2 \cos\theta + 1^2) = 0\\
\implies (\cos\theta - 1)^2 = 0\\
\implies \cos\theta = 1\\
\implies \cos^3 \theta = 1^3 \quad\dots(1)\\
\implies \sec^3\theta = 1 \quad\dots(2)$$
From $(1)$ and $(2)$, the answer is $1+1$